# Bash: append (+=) to nameref (-n) to hash key

Tags: bash, associative-array, indirection

In bash 5.0.17,

```
s='X'; declare -n s2=s
s2+=YYY; declare -p s
```

correctly yields `declare -- s="XYYY"`. So far so good. Now, what if I make a nameref to an associative array key?

```
declare -A aa
aa=( [k1]=v1 ); declare -n 'nk1=aa[k1]'
nk1+=YYY; declare -p aa
```

(I think the quotes are required, since otherwise filename expansion occurs -- test with `shopt -s nullglob`). This yields

```
declare -A aa=([k1]="v1aa[k1]YYY" )
```

Is this syntax for declaring the nameref (or for appending) wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unable to replicate with `bash` 4.4.20:

```sh
$ declare -A aa=( [k1]=v1 )
$ declare -n 'nk1=aa[k1]'
$ nk1+=YYY
$ declare -p aa
declare -A aa=([k1]="v1YYY" )
```

However, on a system with `bash` 5.1.4, I get `declare -A aa=([k1]="v1aa[k1]YYY" )` just like you saw with 5.0.17. So it appears there's a bug that was introduced at some point in the 5.X series.

Comment: @usretc Actually, I think I'm completely off here.

Comment: @usretc Yeah, my first attempt at an answer was in the wrong ballpark completely. See edit.

Comment: Aha. Bash 5.0.17 (Ubuntu 20.04) here. Should have thought to check with bash44, I have it installed as well.

Comment: @usretc I do get the same thing as you with bash 5.1.4...

Comment: Time to `bashbug` perhaps. Though it means I can't really use this in my scripts...

Comment: @usretc You can still use `declare ...`, but need to change assignment to `nk1="${nk1}YYY"`